# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_product() or global $product not working.I am unable to access product price, and length

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, fpdf

I am facing the following error on WordPress: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function **get_product();**
I am unable to access the product SKU, price, and length. I am using **global $product** but it's not working.
I am stuck on it for the last 3 days I have tried s many things but I couldn't find a single working solution.

```
    function output_pdf() {
        $posts = get_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
        $args     = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );            $productListt = get_posts( $args );

        if( ! empty( $productListt ) ) {
            global $product;
            global $pdf;
            global $woocommerce;
            
            foreach( $productListt as $item ) 
            {
                global $products;
                
                if( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0.0', ">=" ) ) {
                    $product =  wc_get_product( $posts->ID );
                } 
            else {
                    $product =  get_product( $posts->ID );
                }

                if(!$product) {
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                    $pdf->Output('D','WooCatlog.pdf');
                    return false;
                }
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $price =  $product->get_price_html();
                $price = htmlspecialchars_decode($price);
                $price = str_replace(array('&#8381;'), 'RUB', $price);

                // Product Price
                $pdf->Ln(10);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
                $pdf->WriteHTML($price);
                $sku =  $product->get_sku();

                // Product Sku
                $pdf->Ln(10);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
                $pdf->WriteHTML($sku);

                // Product Title
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 22 );
                $pdf->Write($title_line_height,$item->post_title );

                // Add a line break
                $pdf->Ln(15);

                // Post ID
                $pdf->Ln(10);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
                $pdf->WriteHTML($item->ID);
                
                // Product Content
                $pdf->Ln(10);
                $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 12 );
                $pdf->WriteHTML($item->post_content);
                
            }

        }

        $pdf->Output('D','WooCatlog.pdf');
        exit;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'output_pdf');
```

Comment: i am trying to plugin my self

Answer (score 0):

```
function output_pdf() {
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'numberposts' => -1);

    $productListt = get_posts($args);

    if (!empty($productListt)) {

        global $pdf;
        global $woocommerce;

        foreach ($productListt as $product_post) {

            if (version_compare($woocommerce->version, '3.0.0', ">=")) {
                $product = wc_get_product($product_post->ID);
            }

            if (!$product) {
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->Output('D', 'WooCatlog.pdf');
                return false;
            }
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $price = $product->get_price_html();
            $price = htmlspecialchars_decode($price);
            $price = str_replace(array('&#8381;'), 'RUB', $price);

            // Product Price
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($price);
            $sku = $product->get_sku();

            // Product Sku
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($sku);

            // Product Title
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 22);
            $pdf->Write($title_line_height, $product->get_name());

            // Add a line break
            $pdf->Ln(15);

            // Post ID
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($product->get_id());

            // Product Content
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $pdf->WriteHTML($product->get_description());
        }
    }

    $pdf->Output('D', 'WooCatlog.pdf');
    exit;
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'output_pdf');
```

Try this

Comment: You have just removed else condition. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: @AhsanNawazBhatti - Please check if it works for WC > 3 and lets add the else back for lower versions :)